# Im Losing a lot of rep to edits that are not really necessary

Tags: discussion, support, editing

I'm getting a lot of edits that are personal opinion, like the order of words, where I put links (see [THIS](https://superuser.com/posts/1329724/revisions) example). Is there any way I can not accept the edits? There was also some capitalization, such as that of RAM, but should I really have to spend 30 minutes spellchecking and grammar checking my work when people will understand me fine either way?

Comment: You don't lose any rep if an edit to your posts get approved, and those edits improve the quality of the posts. Pretty sure they aren't personal either, and yes, it is preferable for your posts to have proper spelling and grammar. You have nothing to worry about here, enjoy your time on the site :)

Comment: The edits that were made to that question only improved the question.  Order of words is important.  Additionally, removing statements like “thanks” at end of your question is something editors are encouraged to do.

Comment: Okay, my bad, there were downwards arrows with a "2" I thought I had lost 2 rep. Thanks for your help and understanding everyone.

Comment: If your question had a positive score of 2, you earned reputation, you didn’t lose it.  However, your example question earned a single upvote, and no downvotes. If your receiving downvotes to something you submitted it should be improved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Is there any way I can not accept the edits?

The original poster can always revert edits.

In this particular case I advise you not to do so, because, in addition to correcting capitalisation, the editor was kind enough to inline your images for you (so that readers do not have to click an offsite link to see the images).

That is a good thing.

From [edit questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/edit):

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do
>   so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post
>   significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you
>   observe.

Comment: Okay thanks, I misunderstood how the edits impacted me.

Answer (score 6):

While there is [already an answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/13132/167207), as [the actual editor of the post in question](https://superuser.com/posts/1329724/revisions) I feel I need to explain.

> “…but should I really have to spend 30 minutes spellchecking and grammar checking my work when people will understand me fine either way?”

Formatting counts, clarification counts, grammar and spelling counts and none of that takes “30 minutes”; more like 30 seconds to be honest.

Why? Easy… In the end **these things only help your question become better and result in better**. Also, you simply providing links to Amazon provides no details at all. And links can go away; especially on shopping sites.

And past any of that, [you state in a comment](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13131/im-losing-a-lot-of-rep-to-edits-that-are-not-really-necessary#comment36361_13131):

> “Okay, my bad, there were downwards arrows with a "2" I thought I had lost 2 rep. Thanks for your help and understanding everyone.”

You didn’t lose rep points because of my edits. **You lost 2 rep points when someone down voted your question** in it’s original format which—[as anyone can see](https://superuser.com/posts/1329724/revisions)—is a mess.

So please, don’t blame editors for you losing reputation. Thank them for actually taking few minutes to make your question more viable and useful to you as well as others.